# Question regarding divisibility with prime ideals

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, dedekind-domain

While I was reading this paper [Lenstra](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiM8emQiPr_AhUCi_0HHcNuCqcQFnoECA4QAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Flibrary.msri.org%2Fbooks%2FBook44%2Ffiles%2F01lenstra.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0xIu0FQZY_aEmahmQx9AX9&opi=89978449) page 15, for d=4729494, he says $2162+\sqrt d$ is divisible by the cube of the prime ideal $(5,2+\sqrt d)$. Can someone please help me how this works?

I see that $(5,2+\sqrt d)^3=(125,150+75 \sqrt d,60+60\sqrt d,8+12 \sqrt d+6d+d\sqrt d)$. How do I proceed from here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The norm of $2162+\sqrt{d}$ is $N(2162+\sqrt{d})=2162^2-d^2=-55250$, which is divisible by 125 (but not 625). This means that the factorisation of $(2162+\sqrt{d})$ into prime ideals would contain 3 factors of ideals with norm 5 (in general, prime ideals have norm a power of $p$, but since we are working in a degree 2 extension over $\mathbb Q$ we can't have a prime ideal with norm $5^3$, and a prime ideal of norm $5^2$ would imply that $5$ is inert and there wouldn't be any prime ideals of norm 5 which makes this factorisation impossible).

What are the ideals of norm 5 in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$? Well by Dedekind's criterion they are $\mathfrak p_5=(5,2+\sqrt{d})$ and $\mathfrak q_5=(5,2-\sqrt{d})$, and $\mathfrak p_5\mathfrak q_5=(5)$. Since $5$ does not divide $2162+\sqrt{d}$, this means that $\mathfrak p_5$ and $\mathfrak q_5$ cannot both be factors of $(2162+\sqrt{d})$. i.e. $(2162+\sqrt{d})$ must have a factor of $\mathfrak p_5^3$ or $\mathfrak q_5^3$.

Now it suffices to determine which of these factors is in $(2162+\sqrt{d})$. Well, notice that $2162+\sqrt{d}=432\times5+1\times(2+\sqrt{d})\in \mathfrak p_5$. So $(2162+\sqrt{d}) \subset \mathfrak p_5$ implies that $\mathfrak p_5 | (2162+\sqrt{d})$. Thus we can conclude that $\mathfrak p_5^3$ must divide $(2162+\sqrt{d})$.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any paper or book to suggest where I can get more info on how to calculate these in general?

Comment: I do understand this, but from $2162+\sqrt{d}=432\times5+1\times(2+\sqrt{d})\in \mathfrak p_5$, how do you make the jump from this to $\mathfrak p_5^3$ divides? Because you say later that $\mathfrak p_5 | (2162+\sqrt{d})$. It is a bit confusing for me. Could you please elaborate this?

Comment: We know that if $\mathfrak a, \mathfrak b$ are ideals such that $\mathfrak a \subset \mathfrak b$, then $\mathfrak b | \mathfrak a$, this is how I deduce that $\mathfrak p_5|(2162+\sqrt{d})$. From my second paragraph I have already deduced that either $\mathfrak p_5^3$ OR $\mathfrak q_5^3$ divides the ideal, but since we know it has one factor of $\mathfrak p_5$, it must be $\mathfrak p_5^3$.

Comment: For your other question, I don't have any specific recommendations but I think most introductory books on number fields and algebraic number theory should cover this.

Comment: Why is it a degree 2 extension? From where does it come from?

Comment: $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d})$ is a degree 2 extension of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @JohnBull I hope my answer was helpful. Please let me know if you require any more clarification of my answer.

Comment: I have a few questions. Will ask them soon? Currently reading some books to understand the concept.. Do you know of any book that explains with numerical examples the concepts of ideals etc.? All the books that I found that they just use algebraic notations and no examples.